# Escape Key-press event lingering from previous action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a custom made dialog box written in JavaScript, it has a key listener to close it if someone hits the escape key.

```
$(window).on(
    "keyup", 
    function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code === 27) {
            _close(e);
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
    }
);
```

Within the content of the dialog is a file input:

```
<input type="file" />
```

I'm having a problem however when a user clicks the file input button and the system file picker dialog is opened, and subsequently closed via the escape key. The system dialog closes, and then the `"keyup"` event gets fired as well, thereby closing my custom dialog box too. It's as though the escape key press from the system file picker dialog is propagating when it shouldn't be.

I would have thought this was a bug in the browser, however I see this happening on both Chrome and Firefox for Mac.

Any ideas?

Edit: I've created a test script for others to see: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vhrxJ

Edit2: I should note, the reason I'm using `keyup` and not `keypress` is because Chrome does not register the escape key press with `keypress` for some reason.

Comment: you can solve this problem by using onkeypress instead of onkeyup, but ive posted an answer below if you want to use onkeyup

Comment: It seems ```keyup``` is required by chrome, since it doesn't capture the escape key event...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oh man, the timer also causes for me dissatisfaction, it seems sometimes the onkeyup fires later than 100ms.
after thinking and testing again i found another solution using the fact that a keypress on a window dialog boxlike alert or file dialog would cause no onkeydown fire only onkeyup.

you would have the same problem if you use an alert box and the user hit escape, your dialog will also close.

so i generate this simple solution and it really works lol, life can be so easily. +++++++

```
 <input type="file"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var windowContent_keyDown;

 window.onkeydown=function ()
    {
    windowContent_keyDown=true;
    }

 window.onkeyup=function (event) 
   {
   if (event.keyCode==27 && windowContent_keyDown) alert ("test");
   windowContent_keyDown=false;
   }
```

Comment: I've filed a bug report with FF and Chrome, since this doesn't seem like expected results. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1013528 and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375405

Comment: i dont think this is a bug, because it also happens in IE.
I think this happens because onkeydown closes the file dialog box, so onkeydown doesnt fire in the window, because it happens on the file dialog, when the key is released the file dialog is already closed and so it fires onkeyup in the window. i think with this solution above, that should be no problem

Comment: it doesn't happen in IE actually. Try it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CwxKE like you said, it closes the window on keydown, which seems like a flawed thing to do, since it leaves the keyup to fire on the window, which is never really desirable.

Answer (score 1):

you are right ive tested it , that really sucks, it tooks me 50 minutes to generate a workaround for that, try this out

explaination:  two global variables.

fileDialogOpen is always false and gets true if the input field is clicked , 
fileDialogOnClose gets true when the dialog is recently closed

there are two ways of closing the file dialog box, 
  first - user mouse is over the file dialogbox
  this would cause the window onmouseover event to fire when the file dialogbox is closed
  so i reset the fileDialogOpen if it was true before and set the fileDialogOnClose

second - user mouse is not over the file dialogbox then the escape button is hit when fileDialogOpened is true in the window onkeyup

```
<input type="file" onclick="fileDialogOpened=true;"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
var fileDialogOpened=false;         //--- true when file dialog is open
var fileDialogOnClose=false;        //--- true when the dialog is closed short time before

window.onkeyup=function (event) 
    {
    if (event.keyCode==27)
        {
        if (fileDialogOpened)           //--- belongs to case 2 - user mouse was not over the file dialog box and was closed with escape, so the fileDialogOpen is true because it was not reset in the window mouseover
            {
            fileDialogOpened=false;       //--- setting to false because dialog is now closed
            fileDialogOnClose=true;         //--- setting to true because dialog was closed short time before
            }
        if (!fileDialogOnClose) alert ("test");   //---- put your code into this if statement

        fileDialogOnClose=false;        //--- resetting the dialog onclose
        }
    }

window.onmouseover=function ()      //--- belongs to case 1 -- user mouse is over the file dialog box
    {

    if (fileDialogOpened)             //--- setting onclose to true, and reseting onclose to false after 100ms, to keep it true if the onkeyup fires shortly after that, because user closes dialog with escape
        {
        fileDialogOnClose=true;
        setTimeout ("fileDialogOnClose=false",100);
        }
    fileDialogOpened=false;           //--- resetting the Dialog Open because file dialog is now closed
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Seems crappy that this sort of work-around is needed. :( Thanks though.